# Find the html tag / document in folder

Tags: html, developer-tools

I have category ipad where I need to add more ipads.
[image]

I got the entire project but it has A LOT of files. Around 20 000 files.
I can't find the html document where the tag is.

When I inspect the element I see the entire html document in Source.
Is there a way to find out the file name / location in the project folder ?

Here is how to source looks:
[image]

I've tried searching for the tag *< span >iPad < /span >* in sublimes Find Files...

But I found nothing.

Any ideas on how to I find the file and add / change the span tag ?

Comment: No, there is no way unless there is a clue. I would suggest starting at a relevant base like the default template file and go from there.

Comment: I would guess that the devices are added dynamically...?